# Enabling navigation tools when dialog is appeared on map?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I created a simple webgis with Navigation tools.The navigation tools is located in a dialog. the problem is when the dialog appeared on map, i couldn't interact with map and the background of dialog is disabled.

How can i enable the background ?

Is there any other options ( other forms,dialogs etc) to add tool in it?

Comment: You might need to create your own dialog since it seems like the default one is made to block the map.  You can use something from Dojo.  I think they have a Dialog class.  You should be able to find it with a little surfing of the documentation.  Just be sure to include the module when loading the map.

Comment: Oh and another thing I forgot.  You could create a div that is hidden and make it movable (Dojo has a class for that) so you can drag it around.  I keep a div with buttons for tools that just gets hidden/shown whenever I need it.